# Google Maps API OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier - overlapping markers are NOT NUDGED

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerspiderfier

```js
var map;
var Sightings = [
{lat:20.735280,lng:-105.401653,title:"Tournefortia hartwegiana",code:'TOHA',sightingid:'40888'},
{lat:20.735280,lng:-105.401653,title:"Heermann's Gull",code:'HEGU',sightingid:'40869'},
{lat:20.735397,lng:-105.401703,title:"Belted Kingfisher",code:'BEKI',sightingid:'40877'}
];

const sightingIcon = {
    path: "M 0 0 L 4 -4 L 4 -16 L 26 -16 L 26 -34 L -26 -34 L -26 -16 L -4 -16 L -4 -4 Z",
    fillOpacity:1,
    fillColor:"#ffcc00",
    strokeWeight:1,
    strokeColor:"#000",
    scale:1,
    labelOrigin: {x:0, y:-25}
};


    function initMap(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('GoogleMap'), {mapTypeId: 'satellite',streetViewControl:false,overviewMapControl:true,scaleControl:true});
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, 
      {markersWontMove: true,
       markersWontHide: true,
       basicFormatEvents: true,
       nudgeRadius: 20,
       nearbyDistance: 40,
       circleSpiralSwitchover: 8,
       spiralFootSeparation:20,
       spiralLengthStart: 16,
       spiralLengthFactor: 12,
       circleFootSeparation:50,
       circleStartAngle: 180});
        var markers = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < Sightings.length; i++) {
            bounds.extend(Sightings[i]);
            var markerData = Sightings[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:Sightings[i], title: Sightings[i].title, label: Sightings[i].code, opacity: 1, icon: sightingIcon});
            markers.push(marker);
            marker.addListener('spider_click', function(e) {}); 
            oms.addMarker(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',maxZoom:18});
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/1.0.3/oms.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js'></script>
<script defer src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=YOUR_API_KEY'></script>

<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div id='GoogleMap' style='height: 600px; width: 100%;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Google Maps API for Javascript on a web page. Creating several Markers from an array with Lat/Lng and using overlapping-marker-spiderfier and markerclusterer for their intended use from an example I found elsewhere.

My problem is that Markers still Overlap one another when de-spiderfied/de-clustered. Clicking on the overlapped markers correctly spiderfies them and shows each. This is confusing to the end-user as they don't know that some of the markers are hidden/overlapped and don't click.

I tried using the Nudge options in spiderfier, but they seem to have no effect. The Nudge options are defined here: https://openbase.com/js/overlapping-marker-spiderfier/documentation

I am wondering if I am not referencing the latest Spider code.

Any ideas how to prevent these overlapped markers? TO BE CLEAR, I am trying to get rid of the issue as shown in the 2nd screenshot below, where the markers are overlapping, but should be nudged a bit to the side in order to show multiple markers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Preferably a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in your question.  The data to reproduce your pictures would be helpful.

Comment: If I provide a reproducible example, then I have to show my API Key, which seems to not be a good idea. Or do I misunderstand that?

Comment: There are keys that work on StackSnippets.  A _tested_ [mcve] with the key redacted would also work.

Comment: Ok - that took a bit, but I have created a minimally reproducible example; exactly as shown in my screenshots. With the data and everything. First time I have used this. Thanks for the pointer and sorry it didn't occur to me at first.

Comment: BTW - I first published the snippet with my api key and it worked. I then removed the key and it no longer works. As per above, you mention that it will still work with the redacted key. What am I missing?

Comment: By that, I meant that I have keys I can use. FYI, at present the cluster icons aren't working for me, so I haven't reproduced the issue yet.  If you want, I can edit your StackSnippet to add a Google test key that works in the code snippets.

Comment: In addition, whether you have Clustering working or not, the problem still occurs. There are a pair of overlapping markers down at that 'point' on the beach that will initially show as "HEGU" (or "TOHA"). Click on that marker to expand and you will get two markers spiderfied. Then if you click again, they stack back on top of each other, but now you see the letters from each showing through.

Comment: Ah! Once you click OK on the Google Error about no API key, it does load and work without a key; but with the "Development Only" watermark on the map. So, right now, it is showing clustering and the overlapping marker issue in full for me. The Snippet also shows an ambiguous script error when you run it at line 0, col 0; but I have no idea what that is about.

Comment: Is the title now OBE? You removed the "nudge" parameters from the OMS constructor, and I don't see them in the documentation.  Where did those come from?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I did not add the Nudge parameters to the Snippet code. They were in my original code listing that I removed. The nudge parameters are documented here: https://openbase.com/js/overlapping-marker-spiderfier/documentation

Comment: I have now edited the Snipped and added "nudgeRadius:20" and added the link to the documentation in the original post.

Comment: If I use the latest version of the OMS (1.1.4, the one that goes with that documentation, not 1.0.3, which you are using in your snippet), it works for me: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gw82bzcj/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of the Overlapping Marker Spiderfier (1.1.4) the version that goes with the [documentation you reference](https://openbase.com/js/overlapping-marker-spiderfier/documentation)

[image: screenshot of documentation referenced]

To get the cdn link use the combination of the GitHub project: [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier by fritz-c](https://github.com/fritz-c/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) and the [version](https://openbase.com/js/overlapping-marker-spiderfier/versions)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fritz-c/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier@1.1.4/dist/oms.min.js"></script>
```

[image: screenshot of working example]

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gw82bzcj/2/)

**Working code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var Sightings = [{
    lat: 20.735280,
    lng: -105.401653,
    title: "Tournefortia hartwegiana",
    code: 'TOHA',
    sightingid: '40888'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.740620,
    lng: -105.394615,
    title: "Rufous-bellied Chachalaca",
    code: 'RBCH',
    sightingid: '40862'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.739182,
    lng: -105.395732,
    title: "Inca Dove",
    code: 'INDO',
    sightingid: '40863'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.738601,
    lng: -105.399059,
    title: "Squirrel Cuckoo",
    code: 'SQCU',
    sightingid: '40864'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.738876,
    lng: -105.397491,
    title: "Broad-billed Hummingbird",
    code: 'BBHU',
    sightingid: '40865'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.736121,
    lng: -105.403218,
    title: "Whimbrel",
    code: 'WHIM',
    sightingid: '40866'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.736850,
    lng: -105.405225,
    title: "Spotted Sandpiper",
    code: 'SPSA',
    sightingid: '40867'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.736135,
    lng: -105.403247,
    title: "Willet",
    code: 'WILL',
    sightingid: '40868'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.735280,
    lng: -105.401653,
    title: "Heermann's Gull",
    code: 'HEGU',
    sightingid: '40869'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.739167,
    lng: -105.395756,
    title: "Magnificent Frigatebird",
    code: 'MAFR',
    sightingid: '40870'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.735632,
    lng: -105.401692,
    title: "Blue-footed Booby",
    code: 'BFBO',
    sightingid: '40871'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.738925,
    lng: -105.397099,
    title: "Brown Pelican",
    code: 'BRPE',
    sightingid: '40872'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.736121,
    lng: -105.403218,
    title: "Snowy Egret",
    code: 'SNEG',
    sightingid: '40873'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.737766,
    lng: -105.401894,
    title: "Black Vulture",
    code: 'BLVU',
    sightingid: '40874'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.740601,
    lng: -105.394636,
    title: "Turkey Vulture",
    code: 'TUVU',
    sightingid: '40875'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.738880,
    lng: -105.397410,
    title: "Gray Hawk",
    code: 'GRHA',
    sightingid: '40876'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.735397,
    lng: -105.401703,
    title: "Belted Kingfisher",
    code: 'BEKI',
    sightingid: '40877'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.740608,
    lng: -105.394595,
    title: "Orange-fronted Parakeet",
    code: 'OFPA',
    sightingid: '40878'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.740620,
    lng: -105.394615,
    title: "Greenish Elaenia",
    code: 'GREL',
    sightingid: '40879'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.740033,
    lng: -105.394573,
    title: "Social Flycatcher",
    code: 'SOFL',
    sightingid: '40880'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.737745,
    lng: -105.403846,
    title: "Tropical Kingbird",
    code: 'TRKI',
    sightingid: '40881'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.738877,
    lng: -105.397251,
    title: "Plumbeous Vireo",
    code: 'PLVI',
    sightingid: '40882'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.738584,
    lng: -105.399194,
    title: "San Blas Jay",
    code: 'SBJA',
    sightingid: '40883'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.739244,
    lng: -105.396119,
    title: "Blue-gray Gnatcatcher",
    code: 'BGGN',
    sightingid: '40884'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.738886,
    lng: -105.397373,
    title: "Happy Wren",
    code: 'HAWR',
    sightingid: '40885'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.738584,
    lng: -105.399194,
    title: "Sinaloa Wren",
    code: 'SIWR',
    sightingid: '40886'
  },
  {
    lat: 20.739209,
    lng: -105.396036,
    title: "Streak-backed Oriole",
    code: 'SBOR',
    sightingid: '40887'
  }
];

const sightingIcon = {
  path: "M 0 0 L 4 -4 L 4 -16 L 26 -16 L 26 -34 L -26 -34 L -26 -16 L -4 -16 L -4 -4 Z",
  fillOpacity: 1,
  fillColor: "#ffcc00",
  strokeWeight: 1,
  strokeColor: "#000",
  scale: 1,
  labelOrigin: {
    x: 0,
    y: -25
  }
};


function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('GoogleMap'), {
    mapTypeId: 'satellite',
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    scaleControl: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6)+" zoom="+map.getZoom());
  })
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {
    markersWontMove: true,
    markersWontHide: true,
    basicFormatEvents: true,
    nearbyDistance: 40,
    circleSpiralSwitchover: 8,
    spiralFootSeparation: 20,
    spiralLengthStart: 16,
    spiralLengthFactor: 12,
    circleFootSeparation: 50,
    circleStartAngle: 180,
    keepSpiderfied: true,
  });
  var markers = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < Sightings.length; i++) {
    (function() {
      bounds.extend(Sightings[i]);
      var markerData = Sightings[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Sightings[i],
        title: Sightings[i].title,
        label: Sightings[i].code,
        opacity: 1,
        icon: sightingIcon
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      marker.addListener('spider_click', function(e) {
      console.log(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+" title:"+this.getTitle()+" spider_click")
      });
            marker.addListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+" title:"+this.getTitle()+" click")
      });
            marker.addListener('format', function(e) {
      console.log(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+" title:"+this.getTitle()+" format")
      });
            marker.addListener('unspiderfy', function(e) {
      console.log(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+" title:"+this.getTitle()+" unspiderfy")
      });
                  marker.addListener('spiderfy', function(e) {
      console.log(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+" title:"+this.getTitle()+" spiderfy")
      });
      oms.addMarker(marker);
    })();
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
    maxZoom: 18
  });
  // map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setCenter({lat:20.736114,lng:-105.403252});
  map.setZoom(19);
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'click', function(evt) {
    console.log("markerClusterer click:"+evt.markers_.length);
    for (var i=0; i<evt.markers_.length; i++) {
      console.log(evt.markers_[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+" label="+evt.markers_[i].getLabel());
      google.maps.event.trigger(evt.markers_[i],"click");
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#GoogleMap {
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div id='GoogleMap'></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&v=weekly&channel=2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fritz-c/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier@1.1.4/dist/oms.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js'></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks geocodezip. I guess I don't see where that reference to v1.1.4 CDN is at on the site. Where did you find this?

Comment: Updated my answer with how I determined the appropriate version from the link to the documentation.

Comment: Hi geocodezip. Unfortunately, I cannot get your code to work outside of Snippet. If I create an HTML file with your style, then script, then html; it fails on the 'google.maps.event.addDomListener() statement with 'google is not defined'.
If I edit my stripped-down-minimally-functional html file that demonstrates the problem but references '1.0.3' of spiderfier, but otherwise works fine, and replace my CDN reference to 1.0.3 with your CDN reference to 1.1.4, it produces many errors; just with that simple replacement. I have been working on this for 2 hours now, and can't get it to work.

Comment: I have tried dozens and dozens of permutations of your code in a simple test.html. At times I am in a catch-22 of Google-before-OMS or vice versa. It mostly works in one permutation, but generates an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromLatLngToDivPixel') at e.a.llToPt (oms.min.js:7:11375) at e.a.nudgeAllMarkers (oms.min.js:7:3470)". And from what I can tell, this is a bug in OMS. And it definitely pertains to 'Nudging'. fyi

Comment: UPDATE: this problem is captured here https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/issues/89. But in my case, it is with 1.0.4 and does not go away on refresh. It also incorrectly expands the HEGU & TOHA from the MarkerClusterer. fyi

Comment: FYI: I still consider my initial problem solved. Thanks Geocodezip.

Comment: The main change I made was to remove the `defer` from the Google Maps API include (and the `&callback=initMap`, replacing it with the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap)`).  That makes it easier to understand the load order and control it.  That is no longer the way Google recommends loading the script as it is inline (as opposed to asynchronous), and takes longer.